# Send messages from google sheets (google apps script) to Microsoft Teams

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, microsoft-teams

I want to use Google Apps Script to send a message from Google Sheets to Microsoft Teams.

I know it is possible to send an e-mail to a channel, but I have no idea how to send a message.

Comment: You could try out sending a message to Microsoft Teams using Connectors. Please go through [Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors). Please let us know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to a Microsoft Team channel you need to know its email address, you can get it in the channel itself with *More Options (⋯)*  *Get Email Address*. Later, to send the message from Apps Script, you will need to use the [`.sendmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) method of the MailApp service. You can find the full options of the method and some examples in that documentation link. Also, keep in mind [Microsoft Team channel limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-an-email-to-a-channel-in-teams-d91db004-d9d7-4a47-82e6-fb1b16dfd51e) (at the bottom of the page) to be sure about the message being delivered. Please, ask for more clarification if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to send emails to the channel. Is there any way to send normal messages like "Hello, I'm the Watchdog", as it is possible in Slack?

Answer (score 0):

@Pierre W Please try using [Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors) to send a message inside Microsoft Teams. However, connectors are built on Teams scope so you can send a message inside a team but not in 1:1 chat.